# in android i'm playing youtube video by YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds in that how to access Full screen button

Tags: javascript, android, html, actionscript-3, youtube

In android i'm playing youtube video by **YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds** in that how to access Full screen button.

[image: **How to remove or access full screen button**]

there is no event specified by that document to **remove/access**. so when i click that full screen button video not playing that seekbar is moving like playing and audio also coming (**so video was stuck audio only playing**).

i added in onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function **fs:0** to remove fullscreen button but it not supported (fs: supported players: AS3, AS2) not for HTML5 [Link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#fs)

So how to Access/remove that **fullscreen** button in **YouTube Player API** [Link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started)